# Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference trying to pass object in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, object

I am getting error: Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference

trying to pass object in VB.net

error occurs on TBS000.Update(U) line.

I am new to this, what am I doing wrong?

```
Public Class Login
    Private Sub BtnLogIn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnLogIn.Click
        Dim U As Object
        U = New User(txtUser.ToString, txtPass.ToString)
        TBS000.Update(U)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class TBS000
    Dim Con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection
    Public Function Update(User As Object) As String
        Con = ConnectDB()
        .
        .
        .


Public Class User
    Private _userID As String
    Private _password As String
    Public Sub New(ByVal U As String, ByVal P As String)
        UserID = U
        Password = P
    End Sub

    Public Property UserID As String
        Get
            Return _userID
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _userID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Password As String
        Get
            Return _password
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _password = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: `TBS000` is a type and `Update` is an instance (i.e. not `Shared`) method of that type. That means that you can't call `Update` on the `TBS000` class but rather you have to create an instance of that type and call the method on that.

Comment: By the way, if you know for a fact that you are assigning a `User` object to the `U` variable, why are you declaring `U` as type `Object` instead of type `User`?

Comment: Also, you ought to be using auto-properties. Rather than declaring a `Private` backing field and a property with full getter and setter, just declare a property like this: `Public Property UserID As String`. The only reason to use a full implementation of a property is if you want to add code to the getter or setter, e.g. validation or raising an event.

Answer (score 0):

To recap in code the comments by @jmcilhinney

```
Public Class Login
    Private Sub BtnLogIn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnLogIn.Click
        Dim U As New User(txtUser.ToString, txtPass.ToString)
        Dim TBS As New TBS000()
        Dim RetVal As String = TBS.Update(U)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class TBS000
    Public Function Update(U As User) As String
        Dim s As String = ""
        Using Con As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")

        End Using
        Return s
    End Function
End Class

Public Class User

    Public Sub New(ByVal U As String, ByVal P As String)
        UserID = U
        Password = P
    End Sub

    Public Property UserID As String
    Public Property Password As String

End Class
```